# Handling 404 and internal server errors with perl WWW::Mechanize

Tags: perl, http-status-code-404, www-mechanize

I am using WWW::Mechanize to crawl sites, and it works great except for sometimes it will hit a page that returns error code 404 or 500 (not found or internal server error), and then my script will just exit and stop running. This is really messing with my data collection, so is there anyway that WWW::Mechanize will let me catch these errors and see what kind of error code was returned (i.e. 404,500, etc.). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to disable autocheck:

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( autocheck => 0 );

$mech->get("http://somedomain.com");

if ( $mech->success() ) {
    ...
}
else {
    print "status is: " . $mech->status;
}
```

Also, as an aside, have a look at [WWW::Mechanize::Cached::GZip](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aCached%3a%3aGZip) and [WWW::Mechanize::Cached](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aCached) to speed up your development when testing your mech scripts.

Comment: `autodie => 0` is the new way of doing this I think

Comment: @surfer190 are you sure you don't mean `autocheck => 0` (like in my example)?  I don't see an `autodie` in the docs.

Comment: Ahh my mistake, this is for [`WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox.pm#$mech->autodie(_[$state]_))

Answer (score 3):

Turn off `autocheck` and manually check `status()`, which returns the HTTP status code of the response.

This is a 3-digit number like **200** for **OK**, **404** for **Not Found**, and so on.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $url = 'http://...';
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(autocheck => 0);
$mech->get($url);

print $mech->status();
```

See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html for *Status Code Definitions*.

If the status code is **400 or above**, then you got **error**...